# Regex to replace x axis with y axis (Java)

Tags: java, android, string, kml

I have a string with coordinates I want to pass on my .kml file. But in order for it to work I have to replace the numbers on the x axis with the numbers on the y axis ([photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwrgZ.png)).I am working on android studio. Is there a Regex for this so that I can use the .replace() method?

Comment: You could probably use something like `yourString = yourString.replaceAll("(\\d+[.]\\d+),(\\d+[.]\\d+)", "$2,$1");`

Comment: Thanks but i doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Works for me (added handling negative values) https://ideone.com/4VYtvc . If it still doesn't work for you make sure you are handling text which you want.

Comment: wow thanks its working after all I tried it again.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how regex works.  When it comes to string manipulation, simple is best.  Try something like this:

```
public static String flipCoords(String input) {
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    String[] coords = input.split("\\s");
    for (String coord : coords) {
        String[] point = coord.split(",");
        if (output.length() > 0) {
            output.append(' ');
        }
        output.append(point[1]).append(',').append(point[0]);
    }
    
    return output.toString();
}
```

Comment: Tried it but the output remains the same